# is a regular $C_1$ function open?

Tags: real-analysis

i know the Invariance of domain theorem but i want an elementary proof for this if its true:

a regular injective $C_1$ function is open.
may be inverse function theorem could be helpful.

help pls

Answer (score 0):

Only regularity (even $C^\infty$) isn't enough:
$$x\longmapsto x^2$$
isn't open.

Comment: :sorry i forgot to write a condition